# Hide mobile safari keyboard when form submitted in Ajax application

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile

I have a textfield which fires an event in a web app, but I'd like the keyboard to close when the user presses enter. Using jquery to disable usual submission.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Create blur event

To open:

```
$('input#search').focus();
```

To close:

```
$('input#search').blur();
```