# Cannot focus on button when focused in textarea in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, focus

I have a textarea which when a user types some text into and clicks the button underneath, the button will not work the first time, you have to push twice on the button to make it work. It's as if the first time you click it you are focusing out of the textarea (the keyboard closes) and the second time is to click the button. This only happens in mobile (galaxy s3 and iphone4).

Anyone know what I can do to stop it from doing that?

This is my js code

```
jQuery('.nextButton').click(function () {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="questionOptions selectionTextarea">
       <textarea rows="4" cols="40" name="s3q1" id="textareas3q1"></textarea>
       <input type="button" value="Next" class="nextButton">
</div>
```

Comment: Its a platform-specific thing. You could try `$('textarea').blur()` but i doubt its gonna work.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589633/hide-mobile-safari-keyboard-when-form-submitted-in-ajax-application) has the same solution as @KonstantinLevin.  I'm curious to know if you get it working.

Comment: The truth is - it still won't work on some devices.

Comment: I tried blur and it works but it compromises the workflow of the form and and messes with the rest of the code on the page, hence why I'm using a button instead of focusout/blur methods

Answer (score 0):

try to add return false;

```
jQuery('.nextButton').click(function () {
  alert('clicked');
  return false;
});
```